# Java Copy Excel to Word without losing font style

Tags: java, excel, fonts, ms-word, apache-poi

I have an excel file with a lot of sheets. I need to transfer some of that information to a word file. If this were all, there wouldn't be a problem. Poi api offers me everything what I need for that task. The problem comes when I need to copy that information from an excel cell to a word file without losing the font style since every cell has specific or multiples font color and I also need to preserve that info.

I know that Poi provides you `Cell.getCellStyle()` method so you can save your cell style but this is useful only if you want to copy an excel file to another one, but not for my case.

Do you know how to make what I need or if is an impossible task? May be I am using the wrong API.

Comment: It is generally recommended to provide some code showing what you have tried - this helps to avoid confusion - for instance, it is unclear if you need help with docx or the legacy doc format (XWPF and HWPF are the API names in POI respectively). In POI, setting style info is similar but different between Excel and Word APIs. Word support generally is lower than that for Excel. The POI examples might help - eg https://poi.apache.org/components/document/quick-guide-xwpf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POI can do it for sure. You need set the font in your new word object.
Like:

```
Font font = wb.createFont(); 
font.setFontName("xxx");
CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFont(font);
```

And if you like to apply multi font in one cell, here are the core code

```
//Set one cell with different font style  
HSSFRichTextString textString = new HSSFRichTextString(fileHead);
textString.applyFont(0,fileHead.indexOf("("), font);
textString.applyFont(fileHead.indexOf("("),fileHead.length(), font3);
cell.setCellValue(textString);
```

Hope helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to copy info from Excel to Word. An Excel cell might have more than one font style or font color. Your example only works for 1 font style per cell but I could be wrong. Can you post a full example please?

Comment: I add some new code and hope it helps.

Comment: I think I realized I made the wrong question. If a cell may have multiples Font Style, how can I manage to know the Font Style of each word in order to get that information and save it in a Word file. That's the problem. Your answer is OK. I will mark it as valid and create a new question. Thanks!!

Comment: This does not seem to be the answer to the question that was asked - the question was about creating styles in Word that match those in an Excel file.